# Problema em configurar "Figuras" no Latex

Tags: latex

Olá, estou começando a mexer no Latex e encontrei um problema que não consigo resolver.
Ao inserir uma figura no Latex tudo da certo, porém, antes da imagem (em pdf) aparece o nome dela, atrapalhando o texto e ficando desalinhado.
Seguem abaixo a linha de código utilizada e o resultado.

Código:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{imagens/Questionario Flipped Classroom.pdf}
    \caption{Tabela com os resultados obtidos através de um questionário respondido pelos alunos que frequentaram a metodologia ativa de Flipped Classroom}
    \label{fig: quest fc}
\end{figure}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tenta colocar no nome do arquivo: `imagens/"Questionario Flipped Classroom".pdf`, com as aspas.

Comment: Assim nem aparece a imagem, só fica um texto escrito a linha de código e um quadrado.

Comment: E se "colocar tudo dentro das aspas"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema são os espaços no caminho da imagem, inclua o pacote `\usepackage[space]{grffile}` no seu LaTeX.

Segue um código de exemplo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[space]{grffile}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{imagens/Questionario Flipped Classroom.pdf}
    \caption{Tabela com os resultados obtidos através de um questionário respondido pelos alunos que frequentaram a metodologia ativa de Flipped Classroom}
    \label{fig: quest fc}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Veja no [Overleaf](https://pt.overleaf.com/read/yfybhdydjzvx)

#### Referência

[How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path)

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo aqui!!